# Add to context menu for specific application

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it somehow possible to add a context menu item for one specific application or can does the application somehow support this? If so what kind of support are we then talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a context menu handler, if I understand you correctly. You need to register it in the registry and, typically, associate it with a file extension.

It's all explained over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If you need to write code to support your context menu handler, then you will be able to find numerous samples of such on the web using the keywords contained in the MSDN documentation.