# Shell Right Click Menu For Custom File Extension In Code

Tags: vb.net

I want add an item in Shell Right Click Context Menu For Example `.davood` Files .

How to create registry keys for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add to context menu for specific application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075743/add-to-context-menu-for-specific-application)